# Order of inheritance for setUp()/tearDown() methods for TestCase and mixin classes

Tags: python, unit-testing, multiple-inheritance

I was wondering, what special thing does the `unittest` do when running `setUp()`/`tearDown()` methods for classes that have multiple inheritance.

Take the following example:

```py
import unittest

class Foo:
  def __init__(self, foo):
    self._foo = foo

  @property
  def foo(self):
    return self._foo

class TestsBase(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    super().setUp()

    self.base_value = 1

class TestsMixin:
  def setUp(self):
    super().setUp()

    self.expected_value = 1


class TestCase1(TestsMixin, TestsBase):
  def test_base_value_is_equal_to_expected_value(self):
    foo = Foo(self.base_value)

    self.assertEqual(foo.foo, self.expected_value)


class TestCase2(TestsBase, TestsMixin):
  def test_base_value_is_equal_to_expected_value(self):
    foo = Foo(self.base_value)

    self.assertEqual(foo.foo, self.expected_value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

When this code is run, the `TestCase1` class tests will succeed, while `TestCase2` tests will fail saying that `AttributeError: 'TestCase2' object has no attribute 'expected_value'`.

Now, I understand how MRO works, and I understand why this error is shown, but what puzzles me, is why `TestCase1` does not have the same issue? After all, wouldn't `setUp()` method from `TestsMixin` be used and `setUp()` from `TestsBase` be skipped?

My conclusion is that `unittest` module must be doing something for this to work. Does anyone have an idea what/how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to my own question. In the end, it all comes down to MRO.

For my example, the MRO would look like this:

For TestCase1:

```
 - TestCase1
 - TestsMixin
 - TestsBase
 - unittest.TestCase
 - object
```

For TestCase2:

```
 - TestCase2
 - TestsBase
 - unittest.TestCase
 - TestsMixin
 - object
```

The problem is, that the `unittest.TestCase` does **not** call `super().setUp()` in its own `setUp()` call.

The reason for this is quite trivial, `object` has no `setUp()`.

This could be easily circumvented in `unittest.TestCase()` by adding in its `setUp()` routine the following piece of code:

```
def setUp(self):
    parent = super()
    if hasattr(parent, 'setUp'):
        parent.setUp()
```

And it works. But this shows another problem. Now my `TestsMixin` stopped working for *exactly the same reason*. I would have to add this guard code in every mixin possible, which is not ideal.

As a result, the better solution is to leave it as-is and ensure you list your mixins **before** your base.